# How to get variable session in jQuery dataTables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, session

I have an API called `all_device` with 1 parameter which is `username` (Image below), so I want to read current logged in user session.

[image]

**This is what I have try.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var username = '<%= Session["username"] %>';
    console.log(username);
    var ManageDeviceTable = $('#manageDevice').DataTable({
        ajax: { 
            url: api_url+'/all_device',
            crossDomain : true,
            type : "POST",
            cache : false,
            data: {username: username},
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataSrc : "data",
        },
    });
});
```

**Console log**

[image]

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$post_data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

session_start();

$_SESSION["id"] = $post_data["id"];
$_SESSION["fullname"] = $post_data["fullname"];
$_SESSION["username"] = $post_data["login"];
$_SESSION["email"] = $post_data["email"];

echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Session created.', 'session' => $_SESSION));
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Where's your PHP code?

Comment: updates my post

Comment: Can you please highlight what error are you facing?

Comment: @sud007, the error is `There was an error parsing the body`, `400: bad request`.

Comment: @mastersuse yes, so edit your question and add the error statement as a blockquote.

Answer (score 1):

PHP >= 7.0 not supports short open ASP tags. You have to change like:

```
var username = '<?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?>';
```

Or

```
var username = '<?= $_SESSION["username"];?>';
```

Comment: ok the session is working, however, I cannot GET information from the API.

Comment: @mastersuse if your initial question is resolved. Please mark this as as resolved with selected solution and ask another question. You should not ask multiple questions on single post. [Ask Multiple Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)